# create outlook rules by populating criteria range from excel

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to create an outlook rule to move all incoming emails with subjects containing user id to move to a particular folder.
So, I have email subjects like - `aaa-bbb-1234-ccc`
here 1234 is the user ID and there are many such user IDs stored in column A of an excel sheet.

```
ColumnA
1234
1111
2222
3334...and so on
```

What I want is to move all emails with user IDs (in the format shown above) from this excel sheet to move a folder called "User1" in my outlook.
I am new to VBA, would be glad to receive any help :)

Comment: There are 2 questions here.  One is how to read data from an excel sheet.  The other question is how to use that data to make an outlook rule.  You should pick one of those questions.

Comment: I would need to get both to solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the NewMailEx event of the Appication class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, MailItem, MeetingItem, or SharingItem. The EntryIDsCollection string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869893.aspx) method and process the item.

So, you may check out the subject line against an Excel workbook data and decide whether you should move the incoming mail item to the "User 1" folder or not. If so, you may call the Move method to get the item moved.

See [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/219151) for more information about automating Excel and accessing the required data.